# Função for Java

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public class Programa{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a = 10;
        for (int i = 1; i<=2; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<=2; j++){
                if((i%2 == 0) && (j % 2 == 0)) {
                    a = a * 2;
                } else {
                    a = a + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("O valor de a é " + a);
    }
}
```

tudo nele consigo entender perfeitamente, menos a parte do for. Testando o programa ele resulta em 54, mas como e porque?
Estou com dificuldade de interpretar ele.

Comment: O que exatamente você não entendeu? Sabe o que o operador `%` faz? Sabe como funciona o `for`?

Comment: Então eu sei que o operador % pega o resto da divisão. O for eu sei que no exemplo do i, ele começa em 1, acaba em 2 e acrescenta 1 para cada vez que soma. Porém eu nao consigo entender como chegou em 54 :/

Comment: Tentou fazer um teste de mesa do algoritmo? Pode ser útil também, para entender a sequência da execução do programa, imprimir a variável `a` dentro `if` e `else` ao executar o código.

Comment: eu imprimi a variavel '-' deu 54 rsrs to tentando entender como chegou nesse valor...

Comment: Imprima dentro do `if` e `else`! Vai te ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute o código abaixo e veja se lhe ajuda a entender :)

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a = 10;
        for (int i = 1; i<=2; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<=2; j++){
                System.out.println("\nCom i = " + i + " e j = " + j + ", temos: ");
                System.out.println("O valor de a, antes do IF/ELSE, é " + a); 
                if((i%2 == 0) && (j % 2 == 0)) {
                    a = a * 2;
                    System.out.println("O valor agora depois do IF é " + a);
                } else {
                    a = a + 1;
                    System.out.println("O valor agora depois do ELSE é " + a);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("O valor de a ao final é " + a);
    }
}
```

Saída do programa:

```
Com i = 1 e j = 0, temos: 
O valor de a, antes do IF/ELSE, é 10
O valor agora depois do ELSE é 11

Com i = 1 e j = 1, temos: 
O valor de a, antes do IF/ELSE, é 11
O valor agora depois do ELSE é 12

Com i = 1 e j = 2, temos: 
O valor de a, antes do IF/ELSE, é 12
O valor agora depois do ELSE é 13

Com i = 2 e j = 0, temos: 
O valor de a, antes do IF/ELSE, é 13
O valor agora depois do IF é 26

Com i = 2 e j = 1, temos: 
O valor de a, antes do IF/ELSE, é 26
O valor agora depois do ELSE é 27

Com i = 2 e j = 2, temos: 
O valor de a, antes do IF/ELSE, é 27
O valor agora depois do IF é 54

O valor de a ao final é 54
```

Comment: acabei de fazer isso. Quando o i chega em 2 e o j também ele faz uma 'nova verificao' para ver se os dois estão em 2? é a unica explicacao para ele somar de 1 em 1 até 13..

Comment: Quando i e j são iguais a 2, ele executa o código dentro do else, pois 2%2 é igual 0. Antes de executar o código dentro else, o a valia 27. Depois de executar o else, o valor de a vira 54 :).

Comment: @Math, acabei removendo meu comentário com o meu erro antes de ver o seu :P. Obrigado pela correção!

Comment: Mas eu pensei da seguinte forma: a começa em 10, i em 1 e j em 0. O programa atualiza i para 2, j para 1 e soma 1 em a. Depois ele mantem o i(2), soma mais 1 para j(2) e soma 1 em a(12) dai ele multiplica o a por 2 pois i e j sao 2, ficando assim 24. Não seria essa a resposta??

Comment: @Guilherme, vou editar novamente, veja se ajuda para entender a sequência!

Comment: Acho que vale a pena ressaltar que o `for` de dentro roda inteiro, depois começa de novo quando o `for` de fora incrementa `1`, pelo que eu entendi o AP achou que os dois fossem incrementados simultaneamente a cada iteração.